# Simple PHP Mailer not send off Goddaddy

Tags: php

I have been trying forever now to make this work and from my understanding this is not rocket science...- My hosting provider is no help and everything I have seen and tried on these forums has no success. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Am I going crazy and am missing something? I am using $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; to see if any error are happening and nothing comes up at all. Literally does nothing when I click send off my webpage. At this point I'm not even taking data from the forms. I just want it to SEND THE EMAIL when i click send!! once I get that working I can finish everything else. Any help is much appreciated. Sorry if this is a newb mistake or something simple.

```
   <?php

    require("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host     = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->From     = "word@words.com";
    $mail->Username = "word@words.com";
    $mail->Password = "poopword";
    $mail->AddAddress("blablabla@gmail.com");

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
    ?>        


    <form class="contactForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post" target="_blank">
                        <div class="contactFormTitle font1">
                            don't be shy, come along & say hi
                        </div>
                        <fieldset class="contactFormDetails">
                            <input type="text" name="input-name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                            <input type="text" name="input-subject" value="" placeholder="E-mail" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="contactFormMessage">
                            <textarea name="input-message" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="contactFormButtons">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Comment: *"Godaddy is no help"* - Funny, this isn't the first time I hear that. All the more reasons I'm glad I never chose them years ago.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You may also be missing something like `$name = $_POST['name'];` as per what this guy's using http://stackoverflow.com/q/16321131/ - and maybe a missing valid `From:` variable taken from your form.

Comment: flee Goddady, while you still can

Comment: Add this after:  $mail = new PHPMailer();
var_dump($mail);
die;
To make sure that your class is found and loading. let me know what you see.

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); and uploaded to the server - still nothing. I have class.phpmailer.php and contact.php in mt httpdocs/php folder on their servers

Comment: @Len_D the `require` would've already caused a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes You would think so but I have seen strange things in my years as a FORMER goDaddy user.

Comment: Found this. You have to read down for the actual post that worked. http://www.webspaceseek.com/phpmailer-with-godaddy-smtp-email-server-script-working/

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy has finally responded with some code that I just tried and IT WORKS! FINALLY AFTER ABOUT A WEEK OF TRYING! This code will send an email! Use this as a Godaddy PHP Email Template.

```
    <h3>PHP - Sendmail Test Script</h3>
This script tests sending mail using PHP and Sendmail. Choose your to and from address, and the       number of emails you wish you send. This can test how quickly email is being send from the shared hosting server.<br />

<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="sendmail.php">
To:<br /> 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="to"><br />
From: <br />
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="from"><br>
how many emails?<br />
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="loops" VALUE="1"><br />
<INPUT TYPE="submit">
</FORM>

<?
$now = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
$emailCount = $_GET['loops'];
$toAddress = $_GET['to'];
$from = $_GET['to'];
$fromAddress = "From: $from\r\n" .
 "Reply-To: webmaster@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


 if ($toAddress <> ""){

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $emailCount; $i++) {
    $body = "This test mail was generated on $now";
    mail($toAddress, "Test email number $i", $body, $fromAddress);
    echo "email number $i sent!<br>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Right... replacing PHPMailer with PHP's internal `mail(...)` call is like replacing a sports car with a bike to fix your engine problems.

Comment: Sigh... godaddy why are you so lame

Comment: For anyone who finds this answer, there is at least one injection security vulnerability in the code and Dark9911 is now helping to host an open relay server.  Do not use the code.  Dark9911's problem was probably using "$mail->IsSMTP();" because GoDaddy is known to block outbound direct SMTP attempts on port 25 because there are spammers out there.  Always use a library like PHPMailer or the Ultimate E-mail Toolkit to avoid introducing security vulnerabilities.